# How to read variable from JS with NodeJS when I change the value in JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I will elaborate little more. I have a variable or should I say an object with random boolean values in JS and in EJS file I will have 2 buttons that I have 2 onclick functions that will change the value of wheels and BMW when clicked to true, something like:

```
var car = {
wheels : false,
BMW : false
}
function changeVar(scr){
car.wheels = scr == 'w';
car.bmw = !car.wheels;
console.log(car.wheels + ' ' + car.bmw);
}
```

And I will export that file to NodeJS with:

```
//JS file || script.js 
module.export = car;
```

and Import it with:

```
//app.js file AKA NodeJS file
var variableCar = require('./script.js');
```

This the ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="changeVar('w')">wheels Button</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="changeVar('c')">BMW Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

this will work good on JS side when clicked(the buttons), the value will change and all that, but NodeJs will not register that and I cannot work with those values, cuz they still show as false in Node.
So my question is: is there a way to read the values after they change in JS, or is there a function/module or something like that will give me real time value of the variables? I am using CommonJS module for this project, and port 3000 if that helps.

Comment: You'll need to send the updated information to the server, i.e. with `fetch`. Making the script available on the client and the server doesn't update one or the other.

Comment: You need to submit a form or make an AJAX call to your server

Comment: Thank you guys that was exactly what I was looking for.